# Об изничтожении слова «пожалуйста»

Tags: обсуждение

Текст вопроса **до** правки:

> Нужна ли тут запятая?
> Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробно, почему она здесь нужна и нужна ли?

Текст вопроса **после** правки:

> Нужна ли тут запятая?
> Можете объяснить подробно, почему она здесь нужна и нужна ли?

Комментарий правки: Вопрос (*можете объяснить?*) не надо объединять с просьбой (*объясните!*).

Спрашиваю, конечно, в первую очередь автора правки (но вдруг — кому-то тоже будет интересно?).
Я не поняла: у нас в тексте вопроса разве нельзя использовать слово "пожалуйста"? Оно считается лишним, что ли?
Или имеется какая-то *нестыковка*, грамматическая ошибка, которую я не вижу?

Собственно вопрос:
[Запятая в предложении с сочетанием «и наоборот»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473541/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82).

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше написать "Объясните, пожалуйста...", а то "Можете, пожалуйста..." и вправду вызывает сомнения. Был такой [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469767/Можешь-пожалуйста-ТАК-МОЖНО-ГОВОРИТЬ).

Comment: Чегой-то, значит, я пропустила. Но такое написание — никак не новомодность. *Он спит, и **можете, пожалуйста, бить** в барабан, палить из пушки ― Сережа не проснется, он копит силы, чтобы жить дальше* (В. Ф. Панова. Сережа (1955)). *А у меня пряжка никогда не пожелтеет... потому что никелированная… **Можете, пожалуйста, потрогать**… И я снял пояс* (Л. А. Кассиль. Кондуит и Швамбрания (1928-1931)). Даже если это разговорный (и, как оказывается, все-таки **давнишний**) стиль, разве он запрещен на форуме? Эти примеры, думаю, будут кстати для какого-нибудь ответа. Может, твоего? "Дарю"...

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, "пожалуйста" хорошо сочетается с глаголами в повелительном наклонении. Просто и вежливо: "Объясните, пожалуйста..." — и нет проблем.

> [Вопрос № 309848](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309848)
>
> Допустимы ли фразы вроде "Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробнее?" или "Не передадите ли, будьте добры, деньги?"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> В разговорной речи подобные конструкции не редкость. Однако литературной нормой они пока не стали, и рекомендовать их к употреблению нельзя. О конструкции *Можно, пожалуйста...* подробно рассказала О. И. Северская в статье «[Можно, пожалуйста, чувствовать себя новой?](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3881377)».

**Из этой статьи:**

> Современное *можно, пожалуйста*,— это, конечно, калька с англоязычной конструкции May I please «Могу ли я/могу я?..», которая поначалу переводилась на русский «как положено»: **May I please** have a glass of water? «**Можно** мне стакан воды?»; Dad, **may I please** have the potatoes? «Пап, **пожалуйста**, передай мне картошку»; а теперь перевод соответствует «тренду»: **May I please** inspect the bathroom? «**Могу я, пожалуйста**, осмотреть ванную?» (хотя и здесь вполне возможны были бы «нормальные» русские формы *а можно мне?.. могу ли я?..*).
> <...>
> «Ванильное», нежно-пастельное, как положено, романтичное, необычное и с глубоким смыслом «*можно, пожалуйста*» хоть и появилось не так давно, но уже настолько распространилось в молодежной среде, что попытки это как-то скорректировать напоминают борьбу Дон Кихота с ветряными мельницами.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, это действительно слишком утонченная и, самое главное, спорная правка. Я откатил к предыдущей версии — надеюсь, автор правки с удалением *пожалуйста* не будет возражать против этого решения.